# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to use Spring Boot using this Maven configuration:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But when I deploy the war package I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d90bff9.<init>()
```

Full error stack:

https://pastebin.com/qmE69aW9

Can you give me some advice what could be the problem?

Minimum example code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cT3F6i8AJReIW6tTb_mtBJiuT8oK7Ca0/view

Comment: is that your full POM?

Comment: Yes, There only some minor configurations.

Comment: Are you packaging and running it as a WAR as documented? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe You can check my main method here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242707/nosuchmethodexception-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-http-httpmessageco

Comment: @PeterPenzov Can you post the complete code?

Comment: @PeterPenzov can you post complete pom? It looks like dependencies versions clash. I wonder why do you place version tag in all deps. Proper SpringBoot usage takes care of deps versions. If you want to change it you need to use <dependencyManagement>

Comment: I created this example project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cT3F6i8AJReIW6tTb_mtBJiuT8oK7Ca0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please check the code what dependencies I am using.

Comment: I downloaded your code and launched a `mvn clean install` and deployed the generated war under my servlet container (apache tomcat 9) with JDK 1.8. The only error I had is related to the DB configuration

Comment: Try with Wildly 13 and configured JNDI.

Comment: In tomcat 9 I had no issue. So I guess you must write some xml for wildfly 13 in order to exclude and or include some modules. I'm pretty sure you must exclude some wildfly module who is conflicting with your jars

Comment: Yes, but how to find which one?

Comment: Well honestly I would exclude all spring modules loaded by Wildfly and I would use the JAR inside my application. But it depends also on your scenario

Comment: ok, but where I can find the Spring modules loaded by default in Wildfly?

Comment: It turns out that the issue is caused by Java 9. How I can enable the required  modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a file named **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** under **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/** with the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

OR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The modules listed above, might be not the one which cause the issue. But this route should work.

Also, take a look at this [spring-boot-deployment-test-wildfly](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/f47d60e7d47f9c91fc453c9c40248ef1d36acaad/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-deployment-tests/spring-boot-deployment-test-wildfly) project.

Comment: Looks like it's related to Java 9: https://blog.sourced-bvba.be/article/2017/12/17/java9-spring/  Can you give some advice how to configure my JVM?