# NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to configure Spring application with Hibernate. I tried this:

Main start method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer, WebMvcConfigurer {

    private BasicAuthenticationInterceptor basicAuthenticationInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter);
        converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
                ((XmlMapper) createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml()))
                        .enable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION)));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(
                createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json())));
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        builder.indentOutput(true);
        builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        builder.defaultUseWrapper(false);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ContextDatasource.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setBasicAuthenticationInterceptor(BasicAuthenticationInterceptor basicAuthenticationInterceptor) {
        this.basicAuthenticationInterceptor = basicAuthenticationInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(basicAuthenticationInterceptor);
    }

}
```

Hibernate configuration called from `rootContext.register(ContextDatasource.class);`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextDatasource {

    @Bean
    public FastJsonHttpMessageConverter fastJsonHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new FastJsonHttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HttpMessageConverters convertersToBeUsed(FastJsonHttpMessageConverter converter) {
        return new HttpMessageConverters(converter);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() throws NamingException {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.datalis.plugin.database.models" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:/global/production_gateway");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager getHibernateTransactionManager() throws NamingException {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor getExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

But when I deploy the WAR file I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d90bff9.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3302)
```

Full error stack:
https://pastebin.com/x30W2aws

Can you give advice where I'm wrong and how to fix the problem?
Do I need to implement the module startup with another configuration?

EDIT:
With Java 8 the code is working without above issue. With latest Java 10 I get the above exception. Do you know what configuration I need to do?

Comment: can you post your pom.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Spring Boot release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-Java-9-and-above), Java 10 is supported by Spring Boot version 2.0.1 and up.  Without a list of your dependencies it's impossible to know if this is the issue, but it does seem like a good place to start.

Are you running Boot v2.0.1 or higher?

Comment: It feels like it's a dependency conflict.  Can you post a maven dependency tree?