# EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search, hibernate-ogm

I'm using this code to configure Spring with Hibernate:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextServer {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        try {
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.plugin.database.models" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        // factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class, Authorities.class);

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:/global/production_gateway");
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I use the factory this way:

```
@Component("authorize")
@Transactional
public class AuthorizeService implements MessageProcessor {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public void processMessage(.....) {     

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
```

But I get exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder
```

I found these answers:
[ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476261/classcastexception-org-springframework-orm-jpa-entitymanagerholder-cannot-be-ca)

[Spring 4 + Hibernate 5 = org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627491/spring-4-hibernate-5-org-springframework-orm-jpa-entitymanagerholder-cannot)

Is there any other solution that I can use? Above solutions are quick hacks.

Comment: Either downgrade hibernate to <5.2 or don't use the `SessionFactory`.. Why do you even need it?

Comment: @M.Deinum I took this example from tutorial. If I remove session factory how I can make Hibernate queries? Is there any example project?

Comment: I used this tutorial http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring

Comment: Why would you need hibernate queries. Use JPA queries. Hibernate is a JPA implementation, start with that. If you really need hibernate you can always obtain the underlying session, but first start with JPA not plain hibernate. If you really want the `Session` use the `EntityManager` to get it, using `EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class)`.

Comment: Can you please paste here example code as official answer?

Comment: I need to make Hibernate queries.

Comment: No you don't... Why do you think you need hibernate queries...

Comment: Let's keep on the main topic. Following the tutorial that I tried to implement how I can solve the issue with casting?

Comment: As stated downgrade hibernate.

Comment: Ok, but this looks like a Hibernate issue to me. In future versions how this is going to be used if Hibernate developers don't change it?

Comment: IN hibernate 5.2 the `Sessionfactory` extends `EntitymanagerFactory` and leading to Spring 5 thinking it uses JPA. This will be fixed in Spring 5.1 but there isn't a solution for 5.0. As stated I highly doubt you need plain hibernate for your use case. I suspect you are equally well off with using the default configured `EntityManagerFactory` with Spring Boot (the tutorial isn't using Spring Boot btw which also changes things!) and just use the `EntityManager` to execute the same queries.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. How I can use `EntityManager`? Can you refer some tutorial?

Comment: Just remove the session factory and transaction manager. And instead of `@Autowired SessionFactory` use `@PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager` (which is roughly equivalent to the `Session`). Also your configuration is still not using Spring Boot (as it seems at least there is no `main` method to bootstrap your application).

Comment: You can see my main method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242707/nosuchmethodexception-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-http-httpmessageco  I use WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: Using Spring Boot you shouldn't use a plain `WebApplicationInitializer` but the specialized Spring Boot version of that, if you don't you aren't using Spring Boot (which will lead to all sorts of weirdness if you actually expect it to do, and also for people answering your questions as you aren't actually using Spring Boot).

Comment: ok, I will try to refactor my code.

Comment: Can you paste official answer so I can up vote the answer?

Answer (score 4):

With the release of Hibernate 5.2 the `SessionFactory` extends the `EntityManagerFactory` interface. This leads to the `SessionFactory` also being an `EntityManagerFactory`.

In previous hibernate releases this wasn't the case.

The easy solution is to downgrade the hibernate version to a version < 5.2 as there is no solution for Spring 5.0 (there will be in Spring 5.1).

Or probably even beter don't use the plain `SessionFactory` and let Spring Boot autoconfigure the `EntityManagerFactory` (done by default if hibernate is detected) and use that instead of plain Hibernate.

Comment: I have to downgrade to 1.5, but at this time is there another way to make this configuration? or could I import hibernate in my pom.xml and use it separate from springboot hibernate?

Comment: @rfcabal noone told you to downgrade to such an old version; 1.5 is so old that it will work with barely anything