# EntityManager and SessionHolder error in SpringBoot Rest API

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

The above query is regarding the project that I am working on:

**PROJECT:**

I have a simple REST based API project using SpringBoot and hibernate where I need to build a registration and login mechanism using GET and POST requests. 
Whenever I am trying to make a POST request to create a resource(create a new user in this case) I get the following error on POSTMAN and also Eclipse IDE:

**POST REQUEST I made using POSTMAN**

```
{
    "userId": "12345",
    "pin": "1234"
}
```

**ERROR ON POSTMAN While Making a POST REQUEST**

```
    {
    "timestamp": 1551809931747,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.ClassCastException",
    "message": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder",
    "path": "/employee/register"
}
```

**FULL STACK TRACE OF THE ERROR**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(HibernateTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:341) ~[spring-tx-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461) ~[spring-tx-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277) ~[spring-tx-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at com.cerner.project.dao.EmployeeDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b4cb760.registerUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.cerner.project.controller.EmployeeController.registerUser(EmployeeController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.37.jar:8.5.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

What might be the issue causing this error? All I am trying to do is a simple POST.

Below are my files:
**User.Java**

```
    package com.cerner.project.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name="pin")
    //@ColumnTransformer(read = "sha1(pin)",write = "sha1(?)")
    private String pin;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private List<UserLog> userLog=new ArrayList<UserLog>();

    public List<UserLog> getUserLog() {
        return userLog;
    }

    public void setUserLog(List<UserLog> userLog) {
        this.userLog = userLog;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public User() {

    }
    public User(int userId, String pin) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.pin= pin;
    }
    //CLOVER:OFF
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userId=" + userId + ", pin=" + pin + "]";
    }
    //CLOVER:ON
}
```

**EmployeeDao.Java**

```
        package com.cerner.project.dao;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.cerner.project.model.Team;
    import com.cerner.project.model.User;
    import com.cerner.project.model.UserLog;

    //@Service
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class EmployeeDAO {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        private Session getSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

        public User registerUser(User user) {
            int userId=user.getUserId();
            user.setUserId(userId);
            String userPin=user.getPin();
            user.setPin(userPin);
            return user;
        }

        public List<User> getAllUsers() {
            List<User> users=new ArrayList<User>();
              User user1=new User(11111,"1234");
            User user2=new User(22222,"4321");
            users.add(user1);
            users.add(user2);
            getSession().beginTransaction();
            getSession().save(user1);
            getSession().save(user1);
            getSession().getTransaction().commit();
            return users;
        }
    }
```

**EmployeeController.Java**

```
    package com.cerner.project.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.cerner.project.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.cerner.project.model.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDao;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        employeeDao.registerUser(user);
        return("SUCCESS");
    }


    @GetMapping("/getUsers")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return employeeDao.getAllUsers();

    }

}
```

**DBConfiguration.Java**

```
    package com.cerner.project.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@Configuration
//@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClass;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.cerner.project" });
        return factory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory factory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(factory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: `EntityManagerHolder.class` and `SessionHolder.class` might be helpful to have because those 2 are referenced in the exception.

Comment: But where am I using them? Could you provide a solution to solve it?

Comment: Drop your configuration and simply rewrite your DAO to use an `EntityManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `@SpringBootApplication` to

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
```

---

With the release of Hibernate 5.2 the SessionFactory extends the EntityManagerFactory interface. This leads to the SessionFactory also being an EntityManagerFactory.

In previous hibernate releases this wasn't the case.

The easy solution is to downgrade the hibernate version to a version < 5.2 as there is no solution for Spring 5.0 (there will be in Spring 5.1).

---

You can Refer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627491/spring-4-hibernate-5-org-springframework-orm-jpa-entitymanagerholder-cannot/38637273#38637273) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294282/entitymanagerholder-cannot-be-cast-to-org-springframework-orm-hibernate5-session) these for more Details

---

**EDIT:**

When you write `exclude=HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class` as a result

> @SpringBootApplication

will not consider that particular class for further execution. As you can see in the image `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` already implemented some classes(which may implement others) for which you don't need to configure anything or make it easy to use, For example, `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class`. As you have excluded the class you must need to manually do the things which `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class` done for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Romil. I have done this. But I dont know why. Along with this change,  I had to make specific changes like removing the HibernateTransactionManager code from DBConfiguration.Java file and adding a Bean to create EntityManager like this-- `public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() `. I dont know why I have to make these changes. Can you help me with this?